fcitx: Typing in Sanskrit and Hindi, Devanagari script (itrans)
I am trying to type in Devanagari script using fcitx and a Spanish keyboard layout. I have fcitx configured to switch between standard input and Mozc for Japanese. I installed the following packages:

fcitx-m17n for Indian languages

fonts for devanagari: fonts-lohit-deva fonts-sahadeva fonts-nakula fonts-deva-extra fonts-samyak-deva fonts-deva


I installed the Hindi locale, but I am not sure if this is necessary.
Currently, my fcitx shows the language options for Hindi and Sanskrit but I cannot switch to them, still only standard and Japanese input.
